# Check if sprite with physics body is out of physicsNode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Using cocos2d 3.0, had my `CCPhysicsNode` and some sprite with `CCPhysicsBody`. Now how to check collision of these bodies with CCPhysicsNode boundary or how to check if these bodies are out of `CCPhysicsNode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot test for a collision with `CCPhysicsNode` because it isn't a `CCPhysicsBody`itself. Generally in Obj-C I use `CGRectContainsRect(rect1, CGRect rect2)` to check if a frame is outside or inside another frame.

For your example I'd use the following solution:

```
if ( CGRectContainsRect(_physicsNode.boundingBox, _yourNode.boundingBox) ) {
   ...
}
```

When using this solution make sure that your `CCPhysicsNode` has the correct `contentSize`, by default it is `{0,0}`.